# IOS app to send location when battery is low

Tags: ios, email, automation, battery, sms

I am looking for an iOS app that can *automatically* send me the location of the phone via email *and* text to a different phone whenever the battery goes below a *pre-defined* limit.

Requirements:

- automatic
- email AND text
- pre-defined battery amount
- sends location
- ***preferably*** send a picture of both cameras

I don't care if I need a Jailbreak, I don't care about the price (it should be reasonable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Last Alert Pro](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/last-alert-pro-find-my-iphone/id510982156?mt=8) is what I've been using for a while now, but I forgot to answer. Although it's not the best solution, it basically achieves the same thing, but due to no other solutions, I'll stick with this:

- £1.49
- automatic (but need to keep app open in background)
- pre defined battery percentage
- sends location
- only sends email
- doesn't send picture
- can sound alarm when battery goes below certain %, so you know you need to put it in charge
- radar tracking via another phone with the app

I also set up 'Send Last Location' via Find My iPhone on iCloud (but this only saves the information to iCloud, for you to check after the battery's dead!). More info [here](http://appleinsider.com/articles/14/09/25/increase-the-chances-of-recovering-your-lost-iphone-by-enabling-send-last-location-in-ios-8).